# Magento 2.2.4 enterprise edition in `catalog_product_entity_int` table they use 'row_id` instead of `entity_id

Tags: database, magento-enterprise, magento2.2.4, cloud

I am afraid, i just want to know in **catalog_product_entity_int** table they use `row_id` instead of `entity_id`. and also other table use `row_id`

I don't understand difference why they use `row_id` instead of `entity_id`, what is the reason behind this change this field?

Check below screen-shoot

[image]

Any help would be Appreciated.

Comment: Did you find answer for this ? I'm also trying to understand the same.

Comment: Please, check in this topic. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/278051/row-id-vs-entity-id-in-magento-2-3-ee

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a reason. I think it's just another naming convention. I am porting a Magento Commerce version extension to Magento Open Source version at the moment. **Disclaimer**: this is just trail and error based.

The code suggests the table `catalog_product_entity` also uses `row_id` instead of `entity_id`.

```
SELECT sku from catalog_product_entity e 
inner join catalog_product_entity_int ei on e.row_id = ei.row_id
```

Changing both `row_id` to `entity_id` makes the query working again. I don't know if this naming has any other implications.

If there is a reason behind this I would like to know of course.